# Having Trouble With Creating a File in Java

Tags: java, ioexception

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Buns {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f= new File("Buns.dat");
            f.createNewFile();
   }
}
```

This program raises an IOException on the createNewFile call can anyone tell me why this could be happening?

Comment: Copied the code over and it worked fine..

Comment: What's the message of the exception? (Note that your code as written won't even compile, because you're neither catching `IOException` nor declaring that `main` can throw it.)

Comment: What is the message that you get with the exception?

Comment: Ahh, I think the OP means that the compiler is objecting about an unhandled exception, not that an exception is actually being thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it around `try/catch block` as [**File#createNewFile()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) might throw **IOException** in case of **IOError**.IOException is a **checked exception** and in java compiler will force you to `handle/declare` checked exceptions in the code yourself.

```
try {
File f= new File("Buns.dat");
f.createNewFile();
}
catch(IOException ex){
ex.printStacktrace();
}
```

From **java 1.7 using [try-with-resource Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):**

```
try(File f= new File("Buns.dat")) {
    f.createNewFile();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStacktrace();
    }
```

If you choose to use try-with-resource statement, the only difference is that you don't need to closeyour resouces explicitly using `finally block. To use try-with-resource though the object which you use inside the try-with-resource statement must implement`java.lang.AutoCloseable`.

You can also propagate the exception by using `throws clause` in your method signature.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

**Related:**

- [**Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)
- [**Offical Exception Tut**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)
- [**Java 7'sTry With Resource Statement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Thanks it worked and was helpful! =D

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    File f= new File ("Buns.dat");
    f.createNewFile ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have permission to create a file in the directory you are running in.